# sms/email template manipulation in an intentional service

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I am preparing message(sms) templates in my spring application. It is relatively easy to do with apache velocity. A simply case (template + code) can look in that way:

*message.vsl*

```
    Dear $lastName $firstName,
Welcome to ServiceXYZ. Your registration with $phoneNumber is being processed.
```

*java class(based on https://topriddy.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/how-to-generate-emails-sms-and-other-messages-from-templates-in-java/ ):*

```
public String getRegistrationMail2(String lastName, String firstName, String phoneNumber) {
       Properties props = new Properties();
       props.put("resource.loader", "class");
       props.put("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");

       VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
       ve.init(props);

       Map params = new HashMap();
       params.put("lastName",lastName );
       params.put("firstName", firstName);
       params.put("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);


       Template t = ve.getTemplate("/message.vsl");
       VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext(params);
       StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
       t.merge(context, writer);
       return writer.toString();
   }
```

However business needs require my templates to become more complex. I would need to have a masked phoneNumber. Moreover the class above will become more generic - it will be a service(let's call it a template service) which will be called by other services(clients). And it will get a list of parameters which should be placed into the templates. Moreover the templates will be stored in database.

As I do not want clients to mask the phone before calling my service how can the masking be achieved on the template service side ?
I am guessing that I need to incorporate some VTL script into my code. If that's the case how can I achieve it ?

thank you !

Comment: If you don't want the phone number to be visible, then just put e.g. `***` into your template, rather than `$phoneNumber`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the question, but I think that you can research the DateTool which can provide some formats.
 Here is the sample:

```
context.add("date", new DateTool());
```

here is the code in the template:

```
$date.format('EEE, MMM d, yyyy at ha', $myDate)
```

Thus, you can create a similar object which is a service.